# execute content in the if statement inside render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, if-statement

I want to execute all lines inside if statement but I can't

this is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
class test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }
  testFunction = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Anything</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>{data.length > 0 ? <Text>Hi</Text> : this.testFunction() <Text>Hello</Text>}</View>
    );
  }
}
export default test;
```

I want to execute (`this.testFunction()`) and (`<Text>Hello</Text>`)

thank you

Comment: please provide your full component codes

Comment: `import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View} from 'react-native';
class test extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
            this.state = {
                data: [],
            }}
testFunction = () => {
return ( <View><Text>Anything</Text></View>
       )
   }render() {
        return (
            <View>
                {data.length  > 0 ?
                    <Text>Hi</Text>
                : 
                    this.testFunction()  <Text>Hello</Text>

                }
            </View>
        );}
    }
export default test;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way:

```js
render() {
  //Is data initialized?
  if (data.length > 0) 
    return (
      <Text>Hi</Text>
    )
  else 
    return (
      {this.testFunction()}
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    )
    
}
```

But there are better ways. For example, in this way you keep your render function cleaner:

```js
conditionalRender() {
  //Is data initialized?
  if (data.length > 0) 
    return (<Text>Hi</Text>)
  else 
    return (
      {this.testFunction()}
      <Text>Hello</Text>
    )  
}


render() {
  return (
    {this.conditionalRender)}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your functions such that they return the component.

```
 condition1 () {
  // do something 
  return ( <FlatList
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
  />);
 }

 condition2 () {
  // do something 
  return ( <Text>Hello</Text>);
 }
```

And call that in the render

```
render() {
 return (
  <View> { data.length > 0 ? this.condition1() : this.condition2()} </View>
)}
```

Comment: i want to add something after `<Text>Hi</Text>` and before `:`

Comment: You can place all of them in another function. refer to my modified answer.

Comment: i have a problem .. i'm use `FlatList` but `FlatList` not display inside function

Comment: What do you mean by FlatList not display?

Comment: Added a FlatList component inside the function. Please refer

Comment: not worked :( ..

Comment: Can you share your complete code?